# Jenkins kills JBoss server when job finishes

Tags: jboss, jenkins

I use Ant to start/shutdown JBoss 5 server through Jenkins. Ant java spawn and fork are set to  "true", so command is executed in the background.

Jenkins successfully starts up the server, waits two minutes (a "sleep" command in Jenkins), then after the sleep it for some strange reason shuts down the server. The sleep command is the last step in the build job. The shutdown says:

```
2013-01-29 17:03:39,332 INFO  [org.jboss.bootstrap.microcontainer.ServerImpl] Runtime     shutdown hook called, forceHalt: true
```

I googled it and tried the suggested -Xrs command, but it didn't help. What is happening here?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Jenkins have something called the *process tree killer* that will kill all processes created by the job (even those started with spawn and fork set to true).

There are some workarounds to this behavior.

- disabling process tree killer

  `-Dhudson.util.ProcessTreeKiller.disable=true`

or

- set the env. var BUILD_ID=dontKillMe in the JBOSS process.

  `export BUILD_ID=dontKillMe`

You can browse the [ProcessTreeKill](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/ProcessTreeKiller) wiki article or [jenkins JIRA](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-9185) to find various workarounds for this issue.

Comment: Neither worked for me on Jenkins 1.653, any other possible workaround?

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Spawning+processes+from+build) source (comments) suggest other environment variables, apparently for older versions of Jenkins. For me it didn't work before I started using JENKINS(_SERVER)_COOKIE.