# Clean way of launching a shell script in background from Jenkins

Tags: linux, bash, shell, jenkins

What's the proper way to launch a script from jenkins, don't get the build hanging, and leave the process running? I can't seem to get it to work. Either the script doesn't run or the build hangs.

If I put in the build's "Execute shell" step `bash relaunch.sh &` or `relaunch.sh > output.log &` or `nohup bash relaunch.sh &`, 
nothing happens; build finishes, but the process doesn't run. I guess it can be related to Jenkins waiting for the [error pipe to close](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30627285/5961990).

If I do
`nohup bash relaunch.sh 2>&1 > output.log`  as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28319984/how-can-i-call-shell-script-to-start-a-backend-java-process), the output is properly redirected, but the build hangs (doesn't finish), and the process dies when I kill the build.

Adding `export BUILD_ID=dontKillMe`, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14584933/jenkins-kills-jboss-server-when-job-finishes), [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/502593/starting-a-forever-process-in-a-jenkins-build-step), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9567441/jenkins-seems-to-be-the-target-for-nohup-in-a-script-started-via-ssh-how-can-i), either to the "Execute shell" step or the script itself doesn't help either. The build hangs and the process dies when I kill the build. Needless to say, my knowledge of linux is very limited.

How do people do this in a clean way?

Comment: I'm nominating for reopen, the answers to this question are correct and the duplicate has none of the correct information

Answer (score 35):

A convenient way to achieve that is to change the environment variable `BUILD_ID` under *Execute shell* which `Jenkins's` [ProcessTreeKiller](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/ProcessTreeKiller) is looking for.

By doing,

```
BUILD_ID=dontKillMe nohup bash relaunch.sh &
```

Jenkins will assume that the background job is not spawned by the build and will not kill them after finishing the job.

Thanks to [Joshua](https://stackoverflow.com/users/436336/joshua) for his observation that you could also use `JENKINS_NODE_COOKIE` as

```
JENKINS_NODE_COOKIE=dontKillMe
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped us tremendously today!

Comment: If this doesn't work, try setting `JENKINS_NODE_COOKIE=dontKillMe` instead - https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/1473/running-a-background-process-in-pipeline-job?newreg=13a0d91a60b34ad19103b50348945dd4

Comment: FYI, you want to use `JENKINS_NODE_COOKIE=dontKillMe` for Pipeline projects, as `BUILD_ID=dontKillMe` does not work there. Source: https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/ProcessTreeKiller

Comment: `nohup` didn't seem to output a file named `nohup.out` like I expected it to. I needed to include `>scan.log 2>&1` just before the `&` so that I could actually check the output from this script later in the pipeline (or manually by browsing the file in the workspace.)

Answer (score 9):

I was having the exact same problem.
I ended up fixing this by placing the following in the Jenkins execute shell box:

```
BUILD_ID=dontKillMe ./grid.sh
```

I moved the `&` inside the script file. Here's what the script looks like:

```
#!/bin/bash
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.0.1.jar -role hub &
```

Hopefully this helps someone!

Answer (score 2):

Interesting solutions.  Has anyone tried screen?

Here's how I run it (for RTL simulation using ModelSim-ASE):

```
screen -S $testname -d -m -L bash -c 'cd build_sim ; make; make sim'
echo Waiting for simulator ...
```

I then wait for our simulator to get to a waiting state by watching the screenlog.0

```
until ((`fgrep -c 'Ready for simulation' screenlog.0`)) ;do
    sleep 1
done
```

Then, when the  other jobs that need the simulation are done running (or Jenkins detects a failure), in the post, run:

```
screen -S $testname -X kill
```

The only caveat is that if Jenkins somehow dies before the job cleans up, in theory you could have a simulator chewing up resources while waiting for something to happen.

To break it down a little:  With screen, '-S' assigns a title to the session (or addresses a running session with that title), '-d' runs detached, '-m' spawn a fork first (which hides from Jenkins watchful eyes), and -L turns on logging (which is also handy in case something in the simulator breaks - you now have a log file artifact with the output).  The rest is simply bash inside of the screen session.

Answer (score 1):

I have implemented the solution as follows:

```
stage('Start AdminServer') {
  sh 'export JENKINS_NODE_COOKIE=dontKillMe;export BUILD_ID=dontKillMe;/app/jenkins/scripts/applyPatch/applyPatch.sh startAdmin' 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've solved a similar issue by executing:

```
mycommand -parameters &> /dev/null &
```

Somehow Jenkins was attached to the stdout of my script.

So I tried redirecting the standard output/error to `/dev/null` using  `&> /dev/null` then adding the process to background using `&` and solved the problem, Jenkins ended the build without killing the process spawned.

PD: I tried adding an `exit 0` at the end of the script, and it was executed, but that didn't free the Jenkins build, it kept attached to the subprocess output.

Answer (score 0):

your Jenkins command box should only contain
`ksh /path/to/script/script.sh`

your script file should look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
command > output.log &
```